# how to program in c to get the char and int separate in c?

Tags: c

Input: AB5, BC2, CD3, BE4

When we input i/p to a program as above. we need to get each string separated by "," and also need to separate string to char by char like getting 'A' 'B' '5' .. how to do this efficiently in c???

I have implemented like storing whole string in an character array and then for loop processing each index of char array to get the char by char by that string..

```
char a[1000] = "AB5,BC2,CD3";
len = strlen(a);
for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
  printf("%c",a[i]);
```

But is there any other efficient way of doing the above?

Comment: Like `strtok`, you mean ? http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok

Comment: Look at the string functions and libraries like Paul suggested.

Comment: @Paul R ya this strtok was the func i wanted..thanks....

Comment: @Paul R is strtok is an best method to use??

Comment: It really depends what you want to do, but for parsing some kind of delimited string then yes, it's probably the best choice.

Comment: @Paul R which is best strtok or strtok_r func??

Comment: @ask: strtok_r is probably better in general, but if you're just learning C and writing simple programs then either is fine.

Comment: @Paul R    when i do like this. it is printing the same string again and again .. how to get the next part of the string.  char *a="a,b,c"; inside for loop strtok(a,","); then i get the output as "a a  a" why???

Comment: You should probably post your current code as a new question on SO - it's hard to answer questions without seeing any actual code.

Answer (score 3):

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ',')
        putchar('\n');
    else if (isalnum(c))
        putchar(c);
}
```

does the same as your program, but without the array, translating `,` to newline and swallowing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in two passes. First, I'd use `strtok()` to separate the data on the commas (delimiter characters `','` and `' '`).

Once you've done that, you can simple separate each character of each token.

Comment: is strtok is an best method to use??

Comment: Everything has a trade off, and I know nothing about what you need to do with the data. So it's hard to talk in terms of absolutes. However, given what I know, I would use `strtok()`, just as I indicated in my answer.